# Merge Lists Together Creating New Sublists Within a New List

Tags: python, dataframe, list, merge

Given a dataframe with 3 columns of lists of the same length, I need to combine elements at the same index into a new list that is also creating sublist. Hard to explain or at least my brain is making it hard to put into words, so given the data below that is put into a dataframe:

```
list1 = ['here', 'list', 'to']
list2 = ['is', 'of', 'be']
list3 = ['a', 'strings', 'combined']

df['list1'] = list1
df['list2'] = list2
df['list3'] = list3
```

I need to loop through the dataframe and combine elements of the same index to create a 4th column who's data would look like this.

```
list4 = [['here is a'], ['list of strings'], ['to be combined']]
```

Ideally I would like all the strings when combined to just be a singular string like I have demonstrated. If that is not possible and they would still be separate elements in the list, that would be fine. (ex: list4 = [['here', 'is', 'a'], ['list', 'of', 'strings'], ['to', 'be', 'combined']]

Answer (score 1):

One option by converting df to Series and then use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda a, b: a + ' ' + b, df.to_dict('series').values())

#0          here is a
#1    list of strings
#2     to be combined
#dtype: object
```

Comment: this seems like it loses much of the benefit of pandas/numpy ...

Comment: I don't think so. 1) unless you are using pandas 2+, you don't really get much benefit using pandas/numpy on string operations; 2) This is converting pandas to dictionary of series objects, so we are still adding Series not individual values.

Comment: lol i see now :P silly me good stuff ... as you were :)

Answer (score 0):

just combine them

```
print(df['list1'] + " " +df["list2"] + " " + df["list3"])
```

if you would like to be more "dynamic" you can make use of the columns in a reduce statement

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(lambda a,b: a # the existing answer (starts as "", then becomes a series)
                         + " " +df[b] # add the new column         
                         ,df.columns # iterating over col names
                         ,"" # initial value (optional...but necessary in this case)
             )
)
```

the resulting series unfortunately you will still have a leading space on so you will need to do something like

```
new_list_of_strings = reduce(...<code above>...).str.strip()
```

in order to remove that leading space...

Answer (score 0):

pending how big your df is, `pandas.iterrows()` may be easier.  `iterrows()` may not be best for a large df though.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['here', 'list', 'to']
list2 = ['is', 'of', 'be']
list3 = ['a', 'strings', 'combined']

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['list1'] = list1
df['list2'] = list2
df['list3'] = list3

list4 = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    list4.append(df.iloc[index].tolist())

list4
# [['here', 'is', 'a'], ['list', 'of', 'strings'], ['to', 'be', 'combined']]
# add new list to df
df['list4'] = list4
```